# Generalizing the Cantor Set to the $n$-dimensional plane

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, cantor-set

I am interested in how to describe an $n$-dimensional cantor set. I think that it may be a good idea to develop
the Cantor Set on the two-dimensional plane at first, but I am having issues
figuring out the split-structure even on this particular generalization. I
am not sure how the splits come into play differently in the two-dimensional
plane; I would have thought that we would develop the cantor set independently
in two different sets and then take the cross product. Is this an appropriate
method?

Comment: Yes, taking the product is the easiest and correct way to build such a thing.

Comment: See [Cantor dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Cantor_dust), and perhaps also [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet).

Comment: It's what's commonly called a Menger Sponge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common constructions is to take a unit square and split it into four subsquares, and then split those subsquares, and so on. For example, if the ratios are all $1/4$, then we'd get the first generation to be

$$[0, 1/4] \times [0, 1/4]$$
$$[3/4, 1] \times [0, 1/4]$$
$$[0, 1/4] \times [3/4, 1]$$
$$[3/4, 1] \times [3/4, 1]$$

Continuing inside each of these squares gives a set with positive and finite $\mathcal{H}^1$ measure. See, e.g. J. Garnett *Positive length but zero analytic capacity* from '70 for an example application.

Alternatively, this can be thought of as a Cartesian product of a Cantor set with ratios $1/4$ with itself.

---

A natural generalization is to replace the ratio $1/4$ with some parameters between $0$ and $1/2$.

Comment: Just for the record, this set it's something referred as "$1/4$ planar Cantor set" in literature.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Right. I've also heard "Garnett Cantor set."

Comment: Agreed. $ $ $ $